# How would I change one date format to another in PHP

Tags: php, format, time-format

How would I change the date `18/08/2018 10:46:15 pm` to `Sat 25, 10:46:15 pm` in PHP. I am doing the following:

```

```
$OldDate = "18/08/2018 10:46:15 pm";
$NewDate = $OldDate->format(D-j, Y-H:I:S);
echo $NewDate;
```

?>```

However, it is not showing anything, am I formatting it correctly?

Comment: Is your question about the syntax error / unquoted format string? If so, what's your IDE?

Comment: You've both missed the quotes in `format()` and used formatting letters that won't give you the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Your old date is just a string. If you want to format it,  you need to create a DateTime object using that string the constructor.

You're also incorrectly specifying the format

```
$OldDate = new DateTime("18/08/2018 10:46:15 pm");
echo $OldDate->format("L-j, h:i:s A");
```

http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php